# error with sending WhatsApp flows as message template

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api, whatsapp-flows

```
//rest of code


//flow
      let message= {
        name: "lzgoflow",
        language: "en_US",
        category: "MARKETING",
        components: [
          {
            type: "body",
            text: "hello there",
          },
          {
            type: "BUTTONS",
            buttons: [
              {
                type: "FLOW",
                text: "lzgo",
                flow_id: 937561724890552,
                navigate_screen: "lzgo flow",
                flow_action: "navigate",
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      };

      axios({
        method: "POST",
        url:
          "https://graph.facebook.com/v12.0/" +
          phone_number_id +
          "/messages?access_token=" +
          token,
        data: message,
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log("Message sent successfully:", response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error sending message:", error.message);
        });
    }
    res.sendStatus(200);
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(404);
  }
});
```

This is my node.js code that request sending WhatsApp flows message, but every time I run it it gives me this error

`Error sending message: Request failed with status code 400`

I checked all the details (flow id, name and language code) it is all the same but it still gives me that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have mixed the two API calls mentioned in the documentation.
Seems like the message variable you have used is building request body for [Creating a template](https://developers.facebook.com/micro_site/url/?click_from_context_menu=true&country=US&destination=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fgraph-api%2Freference%2Fwhats-app-business-account%2Fmessage_templates%2F%23Creating&event_type=click&last_nav_impression_id=2OlB3iXMFLbqbj9Hq&max_percent_page_viewed=98&max_viewport_height_px=959&max_viewport_width_px=1728&orig_http_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fwhatsapp%2Fflows%2Fgettingstarted%2Fsendingaflow&orig_request_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fajax%2Fdocs%2Fnav%2F%3Fpath1%3Dwhatsapp%26path2%3Dflows%26path3%3Dgettingstarted%26path4%3Dsendingaflow&region=noam&scrolled=true&session_id=1SFJPOxi9u5UxueWy&site=developers)
but the Post call URL you are sending is for sending the template as in the example [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/flows/gettingstarted/sendingaflow#templatemessages).

Comment: Thank you so much, you are correct. 
I use cloud API and according to documentations this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/messages#interactive-object) could be helpful